How to identify faulty updates
I was doing a repair (Question How to identify faulty updates?, as indicated in answer 1.  On doing
sudo apt install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop^

I got an error that led me to remove package gnome-software, then I tried again.  This time I got an error with the long error message
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-software : Depends: libfwupd2 (>= 1.7.9) but 
    1.5.11-0ubuntu2pop1.1~1632510283~20.04~5dec90e~dev
    is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I have no idea if I can fix this, or how.  But that's my question: how?

Is this an Ubuntu system or a POP! OS system?

It is Ubuntu (as delivered by System76) altered to be as much like Xubuntu as possible.  So, for instance, it uses xfce4 and lightdm.

The problem looks like an old non-Ubuntu package, libfwupd2, version 1.5.11-0ubuntu2pop1.1~1632510283~20.04~5dec90e~dev. Any idea how that got onto your system? If not, then you should probably clean-install Xubuntu. Or ask System76 support about it. They are good folks; there might be a reason.

The package version you provide is NOT used by any Ubuntu product/release.  You've provided no release details; I do note 20.04 mentioned but libfwupd2 | 1.3.9-4ubuntu0.1              | focal-security  | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x is what exists for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

@guiverc That version may not be referenced by any Ubuntu thing, but attempting to remove it causes removal of three things that look important: gnome-software, gnome-software-plugin-snap and xubuntu-desktop.  So I didn't do it.  Should I?  Could I somehow replace it with a better version?

Your issue appears to be deb package related; starting point is knowing exactly what you're running which you've still not said. Your question makes no mention, and whilst prior comment does mention Ubuntu (delivered by System 76) no critical release details were included. I'd also likely explore the system install detail (/var/log/installer/media-info for example usually indicates media used; though pre-supplied OSes may include their own details/codes; we did that at a recycler I volunteered at; our own build detail mixed in with Ubuntu detail which highlighted it wasn't clean Ubuntu)

The details mentioned are absent because I do not know them, and do not know how to find them out.  Give me commands, and I can give you results.  What I do know is the the manufacturer delivered this with Ubuntu installed, and I modified it to use xfce4 and lightdm, using instructions I found on the web.  That was years ago, probably late 2016.  All has gone smoothly until now, as I upgrades through the LTS releases.  Most of my updates' output were captured, and I have files like did-release-upgrade-20180819-0526.script

@guiverc there is no file /var/log/installer/media-info; the directory contains only dm and version, both modified last in 2017.  Version says ubiquity 2.21.63.4~system76~2.

Those details don't match a Ubuntu system, but instead a System 76 or Pop OS system; ie. you're not using Ubuntu, but a System 76 system based on Ubuntu.

Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Pop forum. (One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Pop OS so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux found in the on-topic link)

The accusations that this is off-topic are bogus.  When ordering from System76, you can specify Ubuntu or their Pop OS.  I order Ubuntu, then change it to Xubuntu.  I'm guessing what you saw that mentioned PopOS was some driver and associated repository.  When it boots up, its saying 'Ubuntu" not System7 or PopOS.
